# вывести картинки циклом на vue.js

Tags: vue.js

хочу вывести li с текстом и картинками

```
<ul>
  <li v-for='item of items' :key="item.class"  class="cryptoblock">
   <img  :src="item.src" alt="">
   <p>{{item.text}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

в data такая информация

```
  data(){
      return{
      items:[
      {class: '1',  src: '../assets/BTC.png', text : 'Bitcoin'},
      {class: '2', src: '../assets/USDT.png',  text : 'Tether'},
      {class: '3', src: '../assets/GAS.png',  text : 'Neo'},
      {class: '4', src: '../assets/ETH.png',  text : 'Ethereum'},
      {class: '5', src: '../assets/EOS.png',  text : 'EOS'},
         ]
         } 
       }
```

текст  и путь выводятся, но картинки при этом не обнаруживаются. Заметил, что при выводе картинки обычным образом к ее имени прибавляются символы и выглядит это так `src="/img/ETH.0d24b27d.png"`

Что сделать чтобы картинки отображались нормально, спасибо.

Comment: `обычным образом` это как? А то `img` и `assets` несколько разные пути.

Comment: Как понять `при выводе картинки обычным образом к ее имени прибавляются символы`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов когда я пишу путь ../assets/ETH.png и смотрю на картинку через код элемента, то вижу /img/ETH.0d24b27d.png

Comment: Вот так сделайте `<p>{{item.text}}</p><p>{{item.src}}</p>`, чтобы видно было что на самом деле отображено.

Comment: @РустамГимранов выводит то, что в data, но при этом картинка не выводится, неправильный путь. В комментарии выше я описывал случай когда прописывал  путь напрямую, а не выводил через item.src

Comment: Ну тада не знаю, может какой пакет `webpacka` их перетаскивает с `assets` папки в папку `img`. Само оно не может перемещаться с добавлением идентификатора к изображению `0d24b27d`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исправленно.
В методах создаём метод

```
getImgUrl(pic) {
  return require('../assets/' + pic);
},
```

Вешаем его на `:src=getImgUrl('picName')`, где `picName` - название нужной картинки из директории `'../assets/'`

Comment: Хеши ж добавляются только к файлам созданным Webpack, или нет?

Comment: @Дмытрык да. Но мало ли :)

Comment: @Emil Rotatew обновил ответ. Это должно работать. У меня сработало.

Comment: @AlexSazonov мне нужно вывести их циклом, в аргументе указать массив или что? и еще проблемы когда ввожу название, выдает ошибку. Ввожу следующим образом `:src=getImgUrl('BTC.png')`

Comment: @EmilRotatew нет, в аргументе указать `getImgUrl(item.src)`, при этом в самом массиве у элементов убрать сам путь. То есть будет `{class: '1',  src: 'BTC.png', text : 'Bitcoin'},`

Comment: @AlexSazonov получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

При указании в src пути к изображению, вы должны убедиться что это изображение живет у вас в публичной папке ибо итоговый путь будет формироваться именно туда.

Папка куда генерится контент настраивается в WebpackConfig.js

Как же эти изображения туда поместить ?

Один вариант, не самый удачный - взять и скопировать эти изображения вручную. В этом случае путь нужно будет указывать каждый раз относительно публичной папки. А в силу того что публичная папка  не должна попадать в репозиторий, это прям совсем плохой путь.

Второй вариант, правильный, как написал уважаемый @AlexSazonov ответом выше делать нужно через require, тогда изображение будет идти через вебпак и автоматически из приватных папок будет копироваться в публичную, однако тут важно не забыть прикрутить плагин CopyWebpackPlugin

Пример как это делается [можете посмотреть тут](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/copy-all-images-files-to-a-folder-using-copy-webpack-plugin-7c8cf2de7676)

В этом случае все ваши картинки при сборке будут жить там где им нужно и к ним естественно будет доступ.

Ну а циферки добавляемые к концу файла нужня для того чтоб у вас не кешировались данные между сборками.

Comment: я сделал так же как было в примере , но я не заметил того, чтобы картинки перемещались в указанную мной директорию, при этом я установил CopyWebpackPlugin и настроил его.
Насколько я понял, сейчас мои картинки помещаются в папку img, но где это настраивается я понять не могу

Comment: @EmilRotatew по идее это все настраивается именно в webpackconfig.  И все изображения поражающие через require при правильной работе плагина копируются в нужное место. Попробуйте поискать рабочие примеры. У меня вебпак обернут symfony encore, по сему мой рабочий код для вас будет неинформативен.

Comment: @EmilRotatew. Вот например в этом компонент импортируется изображение logo.  https://github.com/Kolbasyatin/IFS_2019/blob/master/assets/js/vue/App.vue   А тут обёрнутый конфиг https://github.com/Kolbasyatin/IFS_2019/blob/master/webpack.config.js. Но не уверен что очень поможет